# How to avoid the "blink" when exchanging gifs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, if-statement, gif

I am creating a website where when you scroll into an area, a `gif` appears. It only loops once; if you continue scrolling, it changes to another `gif` (which plays only once, too) If you scroll back, it changes to the first `gif`, restarting it so it can play again.

However, when the changing occurs, there is a blink that I do not want. Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qynvg44b/14/). And here is the `javascript`:

```
$(window).ready(function() {
  var v = 0;

  $(window).on("scroll", function() {
    var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();

    if (scrollTop > 100 && scrollTop < 200) {

      if ($('#container').attr('data-img') != 'http://i.imgur.com/Hhmt8.gif') {
        ++v;
        $('#container').attr('data-img', 'http://i.imgur.com/Hhmt8.gif');
        $('#container').css('background-image', 'url(http://i.imgur.com/Hhmt8.gif?v=' + v + ')');
      }

    } else if (scrollTop >= 200) {

      if ($('#container').attr('data-img') != 'http://i.imgur.com/TUAwA.gif') {
        ++v;
        $('#container').attr('data-img', 'http://i.imgur.com/TUAwA.gif');
        $('#container').css('background-image', 'url(http://i.imgur.com/TUAwA.gif?v=' + v + ')');
      }

    } else {
      $('.imageHolder').css('background', 'blue');
    }

  });

});
```

I tried removing the `?v='+v+'` from the `background-image` but then it won't load everytime it changes... Is there a way to keep the functioning as it is without the blinking?

Comment: preload them......

Comment: it won't animate. the last frame will be shown. you can see this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lj_tang/qynvg44b/11/) and [this one](https://jsfiddle.net/qynvg44b/19/) to see what I mean. There you don't have a blink, but the gifs only happen once

Answer (score 2):

Preload the second image, the blinking comes from the remote fetching time of the image. If you had preloaded the same image at any point on this website before, the new image will be loaded directly from the browser's cache and will replace the previous one without any visible transition.

```
$(window).ready(function () {
   var v = 0;
   var image = new Image();
   image.src = 'http://i.imgur.com/TUAwA.gif';

   $(window).on("scroll", function () {
       /* ... */
   }

}
```

Comment: yes, but if the cache replaces the previous, it won't animate. the image will be the last frame of the gif. you can see this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lj_tang/qynvg44b/11/) and [this one](https://jsfiddle.net/qynvg44b/19/) to see what I mean. There you don't have a blink, but the gifs only happen once

Comment: Don't use the image from the variable, but just load the image a second time as if you would fetch it from the server, like you did before. The browser will load the image and play the animation, but won't have to fetch it over the network first.

Comment: Tried as you said and it doesn't work... check it out [here](https://jsfiddle.net/lj_tang/qynvg44b/20/) it still blinks

Comment: If you add a changing ´?querystring´ to the URL, it means that the image is loaded over the network each time. If you want to get rid of the blink completely, you will have to extend the script by some steps, including loading both images in 2 containers and switching them, for example by changing the z-index. For example you can add a ´onload´ handler to the ´Image()´ object in JavaScript and handle all the maneuvering in such a function. Furthermore the images are both >1 MB large, this adds some additional problematics. Sorry I don't have the time to create a solution.